# jQuery not working on some browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

After loading, [my site](http://www.getshopaholic.com/demo/) should show a list of items from various stores. It does so on my Macbook Pro running the latest version of Chrome and Firefox.

However, it hasn't shown up on a Windows computer running Chrome (although it did work on the same computer in Firefox).

Is there an obvious reason why this should be the case? What's the best way of testing cross-browser compatibility when developing?

**EDIT**

I should say that it is loading *some* jQuery, but it's failing to make a `$.post`.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of chrome and it works, any specific version? did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: The Windows computer was running Chrome v33 which I believe is one before the latest version running on the Macbook.

Comment: Windows computer, running on macbook?

Comment: Windows computer running Chrome v33 - not working. Macbook running Chrom v34 - working.

Comment: It's temperamental for me on Mac Chrome 34 . If I open your link in  new tab it doesn't work. If I refresh the page, it does work

Comment: @3rror404 I've replicated that and noticed that it loads further down. If you scroll down is anything there?

Comment: Yep, just noticed. Everything has crazy top values of ~9000px;